# Skipping scoped variable initialization with goto not producing the desired output

Tags: c, goto

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    goto inside;
    {
        int a = 20;
        {
            inside:
            printf("%d",a);
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it print output as 0, not as 10? Even if it looks for nearest scope ie. `int a = 20` which is not executed clearly. The memory contains only `int a = 10;` so why 0 here?

Answer (score 7):

At the point of the `printf` call, the name `a` refers to the second variable of that name, the one that's initialized to `20`. The outer `a`, the one initialized to `10`, is hidden. There's no reason for the `printf` to print `10`.

The `goto` statement skips over the initialization of the inner `a`, so it's never initialized to `20`. Space is allocated for it, but its value is arbitrary garbage. The `0` being printed is the contents of the inner `a`. It could have been anything.

Comment: Accessing the uninitialized object has undefined behavior, but jumping past an initializer does not itself have UB. There's a constraint (not just UB) for a jump past the declaration of a variable length array, but that doesn't apply here. (BTW, the jump label couldn't be *immediately* before the declaration; only a statement can be labeled, and a declaration is not a statement.)

Comment: It appears that I was wrong. I interpreted the words "variably modified type" in [section 6.8.6.1 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.1) as a "non-const type", but after doing some further reading, I discovered that it rather means "VLA type". Therefore, I have deleted my comment and will delete my answer as soon as it gets un-accepted (I can't delete an accepted answer).